# perl IO::Socket::SSL SSL connect attempt failed

Tags: perl, sockets, ssl

on i start io::socket::ssl tls conncetion

> my example it is work with google and facebook but it is not work with sip tls server
>
> that is sip tls server
>
> I am having trouble skipping the certificate

```
#/usr/bin/perl
use IO::Socket::SSL;

start_connection("2.50.44.55:5061");

sub start_connection{
    my @parms = @_;
    my $host  = $parms[0];
 
    my $sock = IO::Socket::SSL->new(
        PeerAddr => $host,
        SSL_startHandshake => 0,
    ) or die $!;
    $sock->connect_SSL() or die $SSL_ERROR;
    print "Good Connection"
}
```

> on i setart conncet i have this error
>
> SSL connect attempt failed error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed at dd.pl line 14

Comment: Please visit the following [web page](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/libio-socket-ssl-perl/IO::Socket::SSL.3pm.en.html).

Comment: @PolarBear    my example it is work with google and facebook but it is not work with sip tls server

Comment: Does your SIP server has valid SSL certificate?

Comment: @PolarBear    the server it is work with other c# program .. but not work with my perl  socket program

Comment: Perl attempts to verify server SSL certificate and for some reason verification fails. If you have self signed certificate then you need to provide it to your perl script otherwise it can not use it. If you obtain the certificate from _trusted CA_ then the problem should not manifest itself.

Comment: If you have a certificate which is not signed by a public CA (as it seems to be the case here) you need to somehow mark the certificate or the issuing CA as trusted. See options `SSL_ca_file`, `SSL_ca_path` and `SSL_fingerprint` for ways to do this. As for your C# program: either it does not check the certificate or it made the issuing CA or this specific certificate somehow trusted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using a self-signed certificate here. IO::Socket::SSL by default checks that the certificate can be trusted and a self-signed certificate cannot be trusted unless explicitly known by the client. While you could simply disable certificate validation this would basically disable any meaningful security since some man in the middle attacker could impersonate the real server without the client noticing it.

The best way would probably to get a certificate signed by a publicly trusted CA, like Let's Encrypt. If you insist on using a self-signed certificate though you might specifically trust this certificate by using the `SSL_fingerprint` option.

To get the necessary certificate fingerprint:

```
 $ echo | openssl s_client -connect 2.50.44.55:5061 |\
    openssl x509 -noout -fingerprint
 ...
 SHA1 Fingerprint=CE:68:62:68:30:EA:F4:64:82:F5:5C:B7:FB:F4:DA:1B:77:88:9F:DD
```

Then to use this fingerprint with IO::Socket::SSL

```
my $sock = IO::Socket::SSL->new(
    PeerAddr => '2.50.44.55:5061',
    SSL_fingerprint => 'sha1$CE68626830EAF46482F55CB7FBF4DA1B77889FDD'
) or die $SSL_ERROR;
```